# Datatables - Uncaught TypeError: ba is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The error I had was:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: ba is undefined"
"https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.js:119"
```

No other errors are shown. I put Jquery first in the list and checked all the paths work. I also got what I think is the most appropriate [link](https://www.datatables.net/download/) from the datatables site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Ajax Filter table</title>    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#table').DataTable();
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>one</th>
                    <th>two</th>
                    <th>three</th>
                    <th>four</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>one</td>
                    <td>two</td>
                    <td>three</td>
                    <td>four</td>
                </tr>                
            </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

The solution was to construct the table in a way that datatables likes. There is nothing about this on their homepage where they tell you it's just a case of importing 2 script files. But they require you to use thead and tbody elements. Without this it just falls over and the errors are not at all helpful in diagnosing this!

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue - and yes, the documentation that would have helped you is not on the home page - you have to dig a bit. But, for reference, [here it is](https://datatables.net/manual/installation).

Answer (score 1):

In my case also the number of td was not matching the number of th.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the error was related to the number of `td` not matching the same same number of `th`.